# Does python requests certificate verification require openssl on windows

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am using the requests library for my python client which talks to app servers. I do not want to put the verify=false in the production version as it is blindly trusting. I know that requests APIs support certificate verification.  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification. But I am not able to find the required dependencies for the same. Is installing the openssl separately required on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install OpenSSL on Windows to get certificate verification with requests.

Yes, OpenSSL is required, but OpenSSL is statically linked with the Python Windows binaries, so as long as the `ssl` module is present in your Python install everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I am using cx freeze to freeze my application which needs to make https calls using requests. Should I need explicitly specify to pick the ssl module.

Comment: In my frazen app I have _ssl.pyd which is around 1.15 MB, so i think we have the required ssl module in the frozen app